# How to use groupByKey in Spark java dataset and then execute custom logic along the aggregation?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I am just started learning Spark and using Spark Java for specific requirements. I have a dataset in the following format

```
+------+------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------+
|field1|            field2|              field3|    field4|    field5|     field6|field7|  field8|   BoxId|Index|
+------+------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------+
|  1|         ABC|1234|385a3d24e| 3913647|   751923| 191|9977908|321799809|   1334|
|  1|       DFC|385a3d24e|3913637| 40010625|751923| 357.0|    9877908|321799841|   1332|
|  1|        SDC|385a3d24e|3913637|399787631|751923| 245.0|    363908|321799835|   1332|
|  1|       GFF|385a3d24e|3913637|399146918|751923| 275.0|    6977908|321799809|   1334|
|  1|       GFF|385a3d24e|3913637|399146918|751923| 275.0|    7975908|321799809|   1335|
```

I want to groupby the BoxId and save the df for each group Index wise

like for Boxid
321799809
the dataframe would be

```
+------+------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------+
|field1|            field2|              field3|    field4|    field5|     field6|field7|  field8|   BoxId|Index|
+------+------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------+
|  1|         ABC|1234|385a3d24e| 3913647|   751923| 191|9977908|321799809|   1334|
|  1|       GFF|385a3d24e|3913637|399146918|751923| 275.0|    6977908|321799809|   1334|
|  1|       GFF|385a3d24e|3913637|399146918|751923| 275.0|    7975908|321799809|   1335|
```

and file need to be saved as 321799809/1334.csv (This csv will have both the rows ), 321799809/1335.csv ( this will have only one row)

For  Boxid
321799841
the dataframe would be

```
+------+------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------+
|field1|            field2|              field3|    field4|    field5|     field6|field7|  field8|   BoxId|Index|
+------+------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------+
|  1|       DFC|385a3d24e|3913637| 40010625|751923| 357.0|    9877908|321799841|   1332|
```

and file needs to be saved as 321799841/1332.csv.

For this, I was thinking of writing a custom function as the save file logic is custom, like below

The idea came from reading
[groupByKey in Spark dataset, execute custom logic along the aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50556415/groupbykey-in-spark-dataset-execute-custom-logic-along-the-aggregation) this thread

```
Sample custom function to write csv
 
writeCsv(df){
if(!file.exist(df.col(Index)))
    csvWrite(df); // where csv fields are filled.
else{
   append row

}

then use

df.groupByKey(t=>t.BoxId).mapGroups((df)=> writeCsv(df));
```

But the java Syntax of groupByKey takes two parameters i.e a Function and Encoder for which I was not able to find any example.

What I tried to do is create an encoder with a POJO where pojo class contains the fields of the above dataframe.

```
Encoder<POJO> pojoEncoder = Encoders.bean(POJO.class);

df.as(probeEncoder).groupByKey(t->{return t.BoxId;}, pojoEncoder).mapGroups(); but it gives error at groupByKey()
```

Can anyone help me with some java examples of groupByKey? in java.

Comment: would [partitionBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#partitionBy-java.lang.String...-) help?: `df.write.option("header", True).partitionBy("BoxId").csv("output")'`

Comment: @werner tried to use that but there are two issues I want to save the files in custom location format like `boxid/indexid.csv` like `321799841/1332.csv` using the write option it doesn't provide to customize the filename and folder structure if the above is used it is saved as Boxid= 321799841/part-0000-as2324343.csv. Second, when I tried it's very slow in writing files this way.